# Clear Prestashop cart if the last product in the cart specific category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

I have some products in a category (ID 10 for exapmle), this products normally can't see in the navigation because its additional products and cannot ordering without ordering a product outside of category 10. This products can only add in the shopping cart summary page.

I add a normal product to the cart, and after the summary page I can add over a Fancybox a additional product from category 10 to the cart. This works.

But if I delete all normal products from the cart I also need to delete automatically all products from category 10 from the cart, because this product(s) cannot ordering without ordering normal products.

I think its something in ajax-cart.js but I don't know exactly the way to specify the category watch.

Comment: anyone a idea? maybe i modified the CartController.php?

Comment: Are you using a module?

Comment: which uses version of prestashop ?

Comment: No i dont use any module, my version is 1.6.0.14

Answer (score 2):

There is a hook `actionAfterDeleteProductInCart` which runs after removing product from cart where you can do your checks. So create a module with this code.

```
class CartExtraProductsCleaner extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'cartextraproductscleaner';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'whatever';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Cart extra products cleaner.');
        $this->description = $this->l('Module deletes additional products from cart when there are no standalone products in cart.');
    }

    public function install() {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionAfterDeleteProductInCart');
    }

    public function hookActionAfterDeleteProductInCart($params) {
        if ($this->context->cart->nbProducts()) {
            $only_additional_products = true;
            foreach ($this->context->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                if ($product['id_category_default'] != 10) {
                    $only_additional_products = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($only_additional_products) {
                $this->context->cart->delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically after every product deletion from cart we check if there are still products in cart, loop through every product and check their default category ID. If only products with category ID 10 exist then just delete the whole cart.

Comment: great, thanks for the code. i created the module but nothing happens. maybe a problem because i have a ajax cart and need a refresh call?

Comment: If you refresh the order page after deleting normal products does it show empty cart?

Comment: ok i found the solution: my version of PS dont have the hook"actionAfterDeleteProductInCart", need more input in the CartController.php in the row 129 Hook::exec('actionAfterDeleteProductInCart', array(
+    'id_cart' => (int)$this->context->cart->id,
+    'id_product' => (int)$this->id_product,
+    'id_product_attribute' => (int)$this->id_product_attribute,
+    'customization_id' => (int)$this->customization_id,
+    'id_address_delivery' => (int)$this->id_address_delivery
+   ));

Comment: great thanks for your help, its easy if i think about it, but i learn now  more and more about Programming

Comment: @user3221012 No that just means that array of data is also available when hook executes. This array of data is available to you in `hookActionAfterDeleteProductInCart($params)`. `$params` is the data array. So for example if you delete a product with id 22, you have that available in hook as `$params['id_product']`.